# extracting data from a database but data must be the logged in user

Tags: sql, vb.net, authentication

I have a login form where users and an admin can login. I have created 2 databases one specifically for the admin to login and change admin password. Then there is one for the users.

The admin windows form  interface can create users and passwords and assign a number to each user.

The database has these columns

Identifier

UserName

UserPassword

UserTimer

When a user logs in they are taken to the user interface which is very basic it has 4 textbox's and a button. I wanted it so that when they press the button the 4 textbox's are populated with there own data. I did not want them to be able to navigate around the database. Or see anyone Else's info.
The code I have at the moment searches the database and displays the top row. 
Can anyone tell me how I can make it search for what ever user logs in.
So in my example below the user once they have been verified will be taken to the user page. Once there they will be told to click a button, in my example "Button5" the 4 textbox's will then be populated with data. I wanted it to be there own data but at the moment it is the first row of data in my database.

```
Private Sub Button5_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    Dim Builder As New OleDb.OleDbConnectionStringBuilder With
        {
            .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0",
            .DataSource = IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "C:\Users\Nige\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MS_Access_SimplePassword\bin\Debug\Database1.mdb"),
            .PersistSecurityInfo = True
        }
    LoginForm.txtUserName.Text = LoginForm.txtUserName.Text

    If LoginForm.txtUserName.Text <> "" Then

    End If
    'do what you want to do
    lblName.Text = LoginForm.txtUserName.Text
    If lblName.Text = LoginForm.txtUserName.Text Then
        Builder.Add("Jet OLEDB:Database Password", "password")
        Using con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection With {.ConnectionString = Builder.ConnectionString}
            Using cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand With
                {
                    .Connection = con,
                    .CommandText =
                    <SQL>
                   SELECT TOP 1
            Identifier,
            UserName,
            UserPassword,
            UserTimer
            FROM tblContacts
                </SQL>.Value
                }
                con.Open()
                Dim Reader As OleDb.OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                If Reader.HasRows Then
                    Reader.Read()
                    TextBox1.Text = Reader.GetInt32(0).ToString
                    TextBox2.Text = Reader.GetString(1)
                    TextBox3.Text = Reader.GetString(2)
                    TextBox4.Text = Reader.GetString(3)
                End If
            End Using
        End Using
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Thanks for reading I know it seems like a big ask, but even if someone can just point my nose in the right direction I'm happy to read more.
I do not understand how the WHERE clause can help me see who is signed in to the database. I could use the WHERE clause to be more specific IE search for a specific row or name. I know how to do that. I just don't know what query to run to check what user has just logged in to the system,.
As for the 2 databases I am just playing with multiple databases at the moment. 
Thanks

Comment: Two things.  First, you only need one database.  Second, a where clause in your query will enable you to filter the results to those of the logged in user.

Comment: Dan how about an example? :)